# jqGrid: selected IDs are lost after changing the filter

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jqgrid

I am implementing the functionality described at [the question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7464138/user-groups-management).

I have looked through [the jqGrid examples](http://trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/jqgrid.html).
See Advanced -> Multi Select.

There is the problem, the checkboxes' selection is reset when you change the filter, so selected IDs are reset. How to store all selected IDs despite the filter change?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the interesting info about maintaining the selection:
[first link](http://www.trirand.com/blog/?page_id=393/discussion/maintain-row-selection-when-changing-page/), [second link](http://www.trirand.com/blog/?page_id=393/help/maintaining-checkbox-selections-through-a-page-operation/).

Answer (score 2):

The selection is temporal in the current implementation of the jqGrid. If you need you can save the array of selected rows inside of `beforeRequest` event handler and restore selection in the `loadComplete` event handle. To get array of selected rows you can use `$('#list').jqGrid('getGridParam', 'selarrrow')` and use `setSelection` method to restore selection.

Comment: $('#list').jqGrid('getGridParam', 'selarrrow') returns an empty array if used in beforeRequest

Comment: @cuzzea: You should more exactly describe the situation (context) in which you use `beforeRequest`. Probably it would be better if you more detailed describe the problem which you have and post some JavaScript code. I think it's better to open new question. Moreover it could be important to know which version of jqGrid you use.